# How is aerogel made?

Tags: chemical-compounds

[Aerogel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aerogel) is a promising material capable of a high thermal insulation. What is the production process of aerogel, is it a cheap technology?

Comment: There is a "Production" section right in the Wikipedia article...

Comment: @Jasper: I guess you feel smarter with this reply, but I did see that section on Wikipedia (I have eyes), and it's not a clear answer for unexpert people.

Comment: @Bea No need to be snippy about it. Since you already saw that section of the article, it would be very useful to us if you mentioned it in your question and explained what exactly you're trying to find out that is not covered by that section. That would help us give you better answers.

Comment: @DavidZ: to ask specific questions about a topic, you already need to have a certain knowledge of the argument. But in that case, the complex answer of Wikipedia would be perfect. I don't need to be more specific on my question because as you can see Dull Unicorn understood that I just needed a simple answer about aerogel and already provided a clear explanation.

Comment: @Bea Yes, exactly. This site is meant for people who have a certain level of knowledge about the topics they're asking about, enough to ask specific questions that wouldn't be answered just by reading a Wikipedia page.

Comment: @DavidZ So you are telling me both to read a wikipedia page to find the answer, but at the same time to be enough aknowledged to ask specific questions that make Wikipedia useless to find the answer.

Comment: Yes. To be precise, I'm saying that the way to find the answer to _this question_, which you posted here, is to read the Wikipedia page. Questions like this should not be posted here on this site. (Of course, you wouldn't know that in advance, and that's fine, but now you know for next time.) Once you've learned more and you know enough to ask a more specific question, then _that_ question might be appropriate to post here.

Comment: @DavidZ I am new in this site and I will formulate better questions in the future, previously researching the argument I wish to deepen here. Anyway I don't think that nobody should be answered the way of Jasper did. Stating the obvious and adding suspension points at the end, really sounds like treating people willing to learn as stupid. If you really wish to help, you don't formulate the sentence in that way.

Comment: @DavidZ I also wonder why the description of Stack Exchange "Here how it works" reads exactly [Anybody can ask a question](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wfsQIhCeAJQaazSgyhY4gg4hpbA1cAAu/view?usp=sharing) and doesn't say "only expert people can ask questions". This contradicts what you told me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90014/discussion-between-david-z-and-bea).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most common technique used for producing silica gels today involves the reaction of a [silicon alkoxide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alkoxide?wprov=sfla1) *(a compound of silicon and an alcohol)*  with water in a solvent such as ethanol or acetone, usually in the presence of basic, acidic, and/or fluoride-containing catalyst.

In essence, the process is *(very roughly)* as follows:

1. Creation of a [colloidal suspension](https://www.britannica.com/science/colloid), a mixture in which one substance of dispersed, insoluble particles is suspended throughout another substance. In this case, the particles are known as *“sol”*. It's precursor is some liquid alcohol mixed with silicon alkoxide, which reacts with the water, bringing the alkoxide molecules together.
2. The first of these reactions is [hydrolysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrolysis?wprov=sfla1). If breaks the silicon alkoxide, producing [silanol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silanol?wprov=sfla1) (Si-OH) groups.
3. These silanol groups then react with each other or with an alkoxide group, forming siloxane bridges (Si-O-Si), and since each silicon atom can form up to 4 bridges, many small molecules collect together to form giant molecules containing thousands of bridges. These large assemblies are called silica nanoparticles and are a few nanometers across.
4. At some point, the nanoparticles reach a critical size where they stop growing individually and instead agglomerate with other nanoparticles, like atomic Velcro balls.
5. Eventually, when enough of them join together, a continuous network spans the liquid solution, meaning that a gel has been formed.
6. The liquid around this network is then carefully removed and replaced with air, while keeping the gel intact *(note that, if the liquid is instead allowed to evaporate naturally, the forces caused by surface tension may be enough to damage the fragile network, shrinking the gel and lowering its porosity)*. This is the point at which it ceases to be called an hydrogel and is instead called an aerogel.

In terms of cost, production shouldn't be unreasonably expensive, although different methods of production may have different costs as they may require different catalysts or different equipment, so I can't give a specific figure with any certainty.

Also note that each of these steps is vastly more complicated than they appear, such that the wrong proportion of water, alcohol and catalyst, as well as imprecise timing or temperature control may cause the nanoparticles to precipitate, forming a white slush instead of a gel.

Thus, if you're considering producing aerogel, for any use, you should first consult a **real** chemist.

Comment: Why don't you describe the supercritical drying? That's the most interesting part!

Comment: The aim of my question isn't producing aerogel in my basement, but have an idea of the complexity of the process because I am interested in technologies that can be applied and used in the future, on Mars, and wether it's convenient to produce them on Earth and be shipped, or if they can be produced on Mars with the local resources, also given the different conditions of temperature and pressure on Mars.